# Всë пройдëт(,) как забронировано

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, оборот-с-как, реклама

Нужна запятая? Похоже на вхождение в состав сказуемого. Фраза, если что, из рекламы.

`Всë пройдëт(,) как забронировано.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Всë пройдЁт (так), **как забронИровано**.*

Это СПП с **придаточным** образа действия, **указательное** слово (коррелят) не является обязательным

Но в сложном предложении придаточное может выполнять функцию обстоятельства **образа действия,** в этом случае оно тесно примыкает к сказуемому (паузы нет).

Тогда на обстоятельство падает **ударение**, а сказуемое  находится в **безударной** позиции. Например:

*Всë пройдет **как забронИровано**, // можете не сомневАться.*

Comment: То есть автор решает, входит в состав или нет?

Comment: Можно так: Всë пройдет как забронИровано. Можете не сомневАться. Здесь предложения разделены, но мысль продолжена. А если продолжения не будет, то предложение без обособления будет выглядеть незаконченным.

Comment: Кстати, лучше говорить "тесно связано со сказуемым". Войти в состав сказуемого не так-то просто.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!